# Send mail when transaction time is behind system time on UNIX

Tags: oracle, cron, unix-timestamp

I have a query to run on oracle that gives output as sid,serial#,transaction start time,sql_id,transaction id.

What I need to do is, whenever a transaction's start time is more than 1 hour behind the system time, I need to run another query with that sql_id and send it as an email.

How do I compare this time output from ORACLE sql and compare it with the system time?

I need to automate this process and add it to the cron on UNIX.

Please help!

Comment: That's a lot of questions at once. Do you already have crontab running? Does it send email already? Do you use sqlplus or something else to connect to the database? What did you already try? Please clarify some more.

Comment: Rather than cron, look into DBMS_JOB / DBMS_SCHEDULER. You can also send mail direct from the database. But I suggest you ask them as separate questions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The function `SYSDATE` returns the current system date.  When you subtract two dates, you get a difference measured in days.  Multiply by 24 and you get a difference in terms of hours.

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$transaction
 WHERE (sysdate - start_date)*24 > 1
```

will give you the transactions that started more than 1 hour ago.  You can also use interval arithmetic if you find that clearer.

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$transaction
 WHERE sysdate - interval '1' hour > start_date
```